# What are some red wines that mature quickly and are available in kits?

Tags: wine, kits, maturation, red-wine

I'm looking for red wine kits that will mature quickly (6-18 months, as opposed to 2-5 years). I like big, complex reds, but I'd like some wine to drink while I'm waiting for them to mature. I prefer the "high-quality" kits that come with 4 gallons or more of juice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used the [Wine Experts](http://www.winexpert.com/) kits (premium and ultra premium). They are drinkable in less than 12 months and are 4 gallon kits.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that most wine kits have something done to them so that you can drink them sooner than if you were fermenting grapes. Check the kit instructions to be certain.

Disclaimer: I've never made wine from any kit but I know people who have.